# video.js how to manage subtitles special characters encoding

Tags: encoding, video.js, subtitle

Video.js works perfectly with subtitles in English but as for the french or the spanish, there're always some encoding problems with special characters like "é, ñ, ê" etc… which result in the usual encoding difficulties on the web when there's a wrong charset.

Yet my pages are encoded in UTF-8… So is there a workaround ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got the same issue.

Comment: @robbclarke Detect the actual sub file encoding and convert it to the same charset your page is in…

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the charset property of the track element?

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/track

Comment: No that didn't work… Actually Subtitles don't display correctly when the subtitle file isn't encoded in UTF-8 too ! So as specifying the charset in the track element doesn't work, I'll try to convert all my sub files to utf-8 !